# How did I just downvote and then upvote an answer?

Tags: bug, reputation, voting, down-votes

In the question *[Is There a Difference Between Entering an Active Stargate on One Side Or The Other?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39519/is-there-a-difference-between-entering-an-active-stargate-on-one-side-or-the-oth)* I reacted, then re-considered.

I cocked up, downvoting an answer which did not deserve that, because I possess less than "necessary" reputation my downvote was not listed on public view but was registered on some database or other. I resolved to take it back by upvoting it.

The thing is, this did not negate my downvote - as far as I can tell - it positively contributed to an upvote - this is something that I did not intend to do.

No judgement intended on the question or the answer. And that's the whole big-thing point. Is this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To undo a downvote, you have to click the *downvote* button again.

As you already found out, clicking the upvote button will cast an upvote instead of the downvote.

Note that both actions can only be undone within 5 minutes of casting the vote. After that window, the vote is locked in until the post is edited.

Comment: +1 Exactley the sort of information that would have been helpfull if listed somewhere users could easily find. Having been a user for nearly 5 years, I am ashamed to not have known this.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up says *You can undo your vote by clicking the same button you used to vote, so click the up arrow to undo an upvote or the down arrow to undo a downvote.* Hovering over the voting button you already pressed says *(click again to undo)* at the end.

Comment: thank you,  I should clarify, I've been a user of "Stack Exchange" for nearly 5 years, this is my first time on "meta", so I guess I'm still figuring out the network's ways. It's no good assuming each site has full terms and conditions attached, which I perhaps did.